# Android send data from Receiver to activity in background

Tags: android

Hi i have BroadcastReceiver registered in Manifest.
And i want send the data from this receiver to MainActivity, an show the data on the lis.
I have everything done In Receiver bud I dont know how to send the data.

when function onReceive will work i send data to activity in background,
this should work even when the application is minimalized.

i trying  this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent .putExtra("value", data);
startActivity(intent );
```

but i dont want go to activity at once the onReceive start working.

Comment: What do you mean by "but i dont want go to activity at once the onReceive start working."?

Comment: sory for my english, i mean when onRecive start and i using this code what I show, is automaticaly go to the activity, i dont want this

Comment: Then when do you want to start the activity?

Answer (score 0):

You should to save this data to preferences/file/sqldatabase in reciever and load them when activity will start

Answer (score 0):

Here an idea of how to implement Preferences and save data and then you can retrieve them on any Activity.

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
       setSilent(silent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```